# navigation bar css remove hover

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have created a drop-down menu using CSS and HTML.

What I'm wanting is for the navigation menu item to turn back to blue when I hover over a sub-menu link.  For example, when I hover over the `Resources1`  heading under the `Resources` heading, I want the `Resources` font to change back to the colour blue.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SSL78/

Can someone advise me how to do this using CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately without using JS....you cant given your HTML setup

Comment: you need js for do it

Comment: As others have said, it's not possible without JS, also doesn't make much sense. When hovering over a submenu item, the parent item SHOULD have an active class, this is standard practice.

Comment: You don't need JS to do it at all. You guys seriously need to freshen up on your CSS. I posted an answer showing how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your `:hover` to the `anchor` tag and not the `li` tag.

```
#menu li a:hover{
    color:red;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/SSL78/1/)

Comment: Now try it. I submitted an update to it. Not sure why it didn't work before.

Comment: I was wondering why it didn't work for me, but then I saw it was because he had that entry listed twice for some reason, and I only saw the first one in the Fiddle. I gave up, when all I needed to do was scroll down one more time :-P